# Set width of a span based on width of another element with pure css

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="setter">
    <span>some variable content</span>  
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <span>
      lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum    
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;  
}
```

**The case:**

I need to set the width of a span inside `.wrap` class based on the width of a span inside `#setter` div dynamically. As you can see in css I'm using `ellipsis` overflow on the second div. The `setter` div content length is going to vary. So the goal is to make the `lorem ipsum` text be not wider than the content of the first div.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/jacek213/pen/pbPkmQ

I want to achieve this with pure css, is that possible? If not, an angular-friendly solution in js (jquery usage is ok) is welcome, however I need it to be efficient because I'm going to display a large number of records built with this structure at once.

Comment: Can't do it with pure css

Comment: This isn't possible using pure CSS.  You would have to rely on JS to get the `outerWidth` (to account for padding, etc) of one element, and then apply it to the one you wish to alter.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's a little bit gimmick but it can be done with pure CSS

```css
#setter {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 1.125em;
}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="setter">
    <span>some variable content</span>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <span>
      lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum    
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution! You can apply this logic to `img` and `figcaption` elements within a `figure` to keep them the same width, independently of how the image scales over different viewports.

Answer (score 16):

I don't really think you can accomplish this with CSS. Try a jquery solution like this:

```
var $setter = $("#setter");
$setter.siblings(".wrap").css("max-width", $setter.width()+"px");
```

Comment: Plus one For being so succinct. Going to test this now.

Comment: Simple and concise. And it works. Nice